# IE8 cutting off background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background

I have the following code:

```
#background-cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat top left scroll; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='background.jpg', sizingMethod='scale'); zoom: 1;
}
```

usage:

```
<div id="background-cover">
    <div id="container">
        <p>Content Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which works absolutely fine in chrome, ie9+, firefox etc. But throws a small issue up in ie8, it doesn't seem to stretch to the bottom of the window - it looks like it only loads the actual dimensions of the image. Is there anyway around this?

background.jpg is in the same folder as the css file by the way

I can't post the link as it's work related, but help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MaxImage2](http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/) library.

MaxImage2 works in all modern browsers and even in IE back to version 7.0.

Comment: Ideally i'd like a css solution. However i will bear this in mind, thanks!